# SFMC multiple email to same email address from different senders

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

Can anyone confirm that Salesforce Marketing Cloud allows multiple email messages (from multiple senders) to the same target email address, in one list?

We manage emails from multiple agents, which few of them may happen to do business with one same customer, so all of them would want to communicate with that customer. For instance, think you bought multiple properties with different realtors.

In Pardot is not possible, but SFMC, being more B2C, it might. Is this true? TIA.

Comment: It all depends on how you set it up, but in general, yes, it is doable

Comment: Pardot - if multiple agents send an email to the same list (or the same customer on multiple lists), as long as the email from agent 1 is different from agent 2, they will both arrive.